# Add Team Explorer to Visual Studio 2019 for mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

I would like to have Team Explorer into my Visual Studio 2019 for, but I can't find it, can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

Team Explorer is not available in Visual Studio for Mac.  It's unique to Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: and what is the alternative for it in mac?